# Using getRange, is it possible to ensure empty cells are ignored?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Attempting to create a Ui prompt for a function that will return 8 separate getRange.getValue variables. I am unable to work out how to ignore any empty cells within the getRange range (i currently get a row of commas for any blank cell).

I have tried this for each range with no luck:

```
var result = [i for each (i in LiDCO)if (isNaN(i))];
    Browser.msgBox(result);
```

I have also tried Filter() that also didn't work for me.

```
var range_input = sheet.getRange(LiDCO).getValues(); var 
filtered_input = range_input.filter(String);
```

Can anyone please help?

Here is my full code:

```
function Handover() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var buttons = ui.ButtonSet.OK
  var LiDCO = ss.getRange(3, 15, 9).getValues();
  var filters = ss.getRange(3, 13, 9, 2).getValues();
  var paedfilters = ss.getRange(3, 17, 4).getValues();
  var nox = ss.getRange(8, 17, 4).getValues();
  var tasks = ss.getRange(2, 7, 17, 3).getValues();
  var checks = ss.getRange("A27").getValue();
  var messages = ss.getRange(14, 13, 5, 5).getValues();


  var handover = ui.alert('DAILY HANDOVER SUMMARY','Please check the following equipment and their bed numbers: '
                          + '\r\nLiDCOs:   '    + LiDCO  
                          + '\r\nFilters:   '    + filters 
                          + '\r\nPaed Filters:   '    + paedfilters 
                          + '\r\nNitric:   '   + nox 
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\n....and remember to update the Dashboard.'
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\nTasks outstanding are:  ' 
                          + '\r\n' + tasks 
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\nThere are ' + checks + ' checks that need to be done today.'
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\nMessages: '
                          + '\r\n' + messages
                          , buttons)
  }
```

I have updated my code and it works now for `getRange(row, column, numRows)` but not with `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` is there something different needed for the extra columns? The full updated code is below.

```
function Handover() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var buttons = ui.ButtonSet.OK
  var LiDCO = ss.getRange(3, 15, 9).getValues();
  var filters = ss.getRange(3, 13, 9, 2).getValues();
  var paedfilters = ss.getRange(3, 17, 4).getValues();
  var nox = ss.getRange(8, 17, 4).getValues();
  var tasks = ss.getRange(2, 7, 17, 3).getValues();
  var checks = ss.getRange("A27").getValue();
  var messages = ss.getRange(14, 13, 5, 5).getValues();

  var filtered_input = LiDCO.filter(String);
  var filtered_input1 = filters.filter(String);
  var filtered_input2 = paedfilters.filter(String);
  var filtered_input3 = nox.filter(String);
  var filtered_input4 = tasks.filter(String);
  var filtered_input5 = messages.filter(String);


  var handover = ui.alert('DAILY HANDOVER SUMMARY','Please check the following equipment and their bed numbers: '
                          + '\r\nLiDCOs:   '    + filtered_input
                          + '\r\nFilters:   '    + filtered_input1
                          + '\r\nPaed Filters:   '    + filtered_input2
                          + '\r\nNitric:   '   + filtered_input3
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\n....and remember to update the Dashboard.'
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\nTasks outstanding are:  ' 
                          + '\r\n' + filtered_input4
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\nThere are ' + checks + ' checks that need to be done today.'
                          + '\r\n'
                          + '\r\nMessages: '
                          + '\r\n' + filtered_input5
                          , buttons)
  }
```

Comment: I had deleted it but it was something like what I have added to my question.

Comment: Do your empty cells have spaces in them that are being considered as a string?

Comment: No they're definitely empty.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LiDCO.filter(String)`?

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, that has worked but only for certain ranges where numColumns hasn't been used, Please see updated code in my question above.

Comment: `getValues` returns an array of arrays. When the number of columns is unspecified, it is 1 - i.e. you get `[ [r1c1], [r2c1], [r3c1], ... ]` If it is 2, you get `[ [r1c1, r1c2], [r2c1, r2c2], ... ]`. Write your own filter function to handle a 2D array. Or... review other questions about exactly that.

Comment: Sorry @tehhowch i don't know how to do that, i have looked at other questions and i still don't understand. An example using my script would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you use the [`String` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) as the callback for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and rely on the ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) interpretation of the nullstring `""` to instruct `Array#filter` to discard the associated row. This fails for multiple columns because invoking the `String` constructor (and thus [`Array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description)) on an array with multiple elements, e.g. `["", ""]`, results a truthy value. The solution is to create your own function to use as the callback for `Array#filter`.

```
function myCB(val) {
  // Check if `val` is an array, and if so, require at least one non-empty element in order for this element to be kept
  if (Array.isArray(val))
    return val.filter(myCB).length;
  else if (val)
  {
    // val is not "falsy", e.g. a non-zero number, an arbitrary object, a string of non-zero length, the boolean literal `true`
    return true;
  }
  else if (val === 0)
  {
    // Do you care about numeric `0`?
    // return true; // keep `0`
    // return false; // discard `0`
    throw new Error("pick a return option for val===0");
  }
  else if (val === false)
  {
    // Do you care about boolean `false`?
    // return true; // keep `false`
    // return false; // discard `false`
    throw new Error("pick a return option for val===false");
  }
  else
  {
    // val is `""`, `null`, or `undefined`, so discard it
    return false;
  }
}
```

Your filter callback will receive 3 arguments per the spec, so any custom parameters should be the 4th or more, lest you erroneously consume the function arguments.

```
function myCB(val, isSpecial) // Wrong!

function myCB(val, index, allVals, isSpecial) // Ok
```